# ocamlfind cannot see installed package

Tags: ocaml, ocamlfind

I wanted to compile my project using command:

```
ocamlfind ocamlopt -package ocamlnet -package batteries -package unix -linkpkg oauth.ml
```

but I'm getting following error:

```
ocamlfind: Package `ocamlnet' not found
make: *** [oauth.cmi] Error 2
```

After some research on this problem I have read that there may be problem with packages installed via opam and packages installed before opam installation (in this case with ocamlfind) so I tried to check that and get stuck because ocamlfind is installed via opam. Does anybody know what may I try to do to solve that problem?

```
$ which ocamlfind
/home/user/.opam/4.00.1/bin/ocamlfind

$ opam list 
Installed packages for 4.00.1:
[...]
ocamlfind             1.4.0  A library manager for OCaml
[...]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23):

Do a:

```
eval $(opam config env)
```

That should fix the problem.

**# Edit 1:**

If it still does not work remove the dir

/home/user/.opam/4.00.1

and try it again.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it's not doing anything:
$ opam config env
CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/adam/.opam/4.00.1/lib/stublibs"; export CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
PERL5LIB="/home/adam/.opam/4.00.1/lib/perl5:"; export PERL5LIB;
OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH="/home/adam/.opam/4.00.1/lib/toplevel"; export OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH;
MANPATH=":/home/adam/.opam/4.00.1/man"; export MANPATH;
PATH="..."; export PATH;
$ make
[...]
ocamlfind: Package `ocamlnet' not found
make: *** [oauth.cmi] Error 2

Comment: You probably meant `eval $(opam config env)`.

Comment: @Michael It wasn't file but whole directory and actually now I have bigger problem (project is still not compiling) because now I'm getting
    $ opam config env
[ERROR] global-config does not define the variable lib.
'opam config env' failed.
and even ocaml doesn't want to run
    $ opam config env
[ERROR] global-config does not define the variable lib.
'opam config env' failed.
Will it guide me somewhere or should I better start reinstalling ocaml and rest of packages?

Comment: Do a `eval $(opam config env)` as mentioned above.

Comment: The same error: $ eval $(opam config env) 
[ERROR] global-config does not define the variable lib.
'opam config env' failed.

Comment: OK, I've just removed ./opam directories and reinstalled opam. eval $(opam config env) still doesn't work. Michael, @JonathanProtzenko Can you reveal the motivation behind removing this folder and typing 'eval $(opam config env)'? It'd help me at trying to find similar errors and maybe move on a little. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[ERROR] global-config does not define the variable lib` is typical of being in a non-existent switch. Try `opam switch 4.01.0` or something like that to switch back to an existing switch.

Answer (score 2):

I'm making answer because of limit in comments and partial results I've made. Here is the result of 'grep -r 'ocamlnet' *' at '~/.opam' directory: http://pastebin.com/8cJqMXDY by looking at lines 1-90 we may conclude that there is actually no ocamlnet library at all (or I'm looking for it in wrong place - but as I wrote in comment everything were installed using opam - I'd be glad to hear some opinions on this subject). These suspicions may be partially confirmed in two ways:

1. in fact in lines 1-90 we've all binaries of ocamlnet components (http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/ocamlnet-3.7.3/doc/html-main/index.html)
2. lines 90-* doesn't seem like something other than some files needed to manage this package using opam. E.g.

   ```
   ~/.opam/repo/default/packages/ocamlnet$ tree -r .
   .
   ├── ocamlnet.3.7.3
   │   ├── url
   │   ├── opam
   │   ├── files
   │   │   └── ocamlnet.install
   │   └── descr
   ├── ocamlnet.3.6.5
   │   ├── url
   │   ├── opam
   │   ├── files
   │   │   ├── ocamlnet.install
   │   │   ├── netpop.patch
   │   │   ├── nethttpd_types.patch
   │   │   └── cloexec.patch
   │   └── descr
   ├── ocamlnet.3.6.3
   │   ├── url
   │   ├── opam
   │   ├── files
   │   │   └── ocamlnet.install
   │   └── descr
   ├── ocamlnet.3.6.0
   │   ├── url
   │   ├── opam
   │   ├── files
   │   │   ├── ocamlnet-ocaml4.diff
   │   │   └── ocamlnet.install
   │   └── descr
   ├── ocamlnet.3.5.1
   │   ├── url
   │   ├── opam
   │   ├── files
   │   │   └── ocamlnet.install
   │   └── descr
   └── ocamlnet.3.2.1
       ├── url
       ├── opam
       ├── files
       │   └── ocamlnet.install
       └── descr
   ```

I do not have a sufficiently large knowledge to go into it deeper but it looks for me like that ocamlnet become just a shortcut for a few another packages used by opam. **Especially** that after changing

```
-package ocamlnet
```

to exact module which I'm using

```
-package netstring
```

everything has **compiled fine**. I'm still open to any other solutions or explenations for the curious case of ocamlnet package (and Michael's hints) B).