# How to build Flow

Tags: facebook, flowtype

I'm trying to build flow so that I can make modifications to their code and build my own version to use and test. But when I'm trying to build it, it dies. The following steps were used:

1. Install OCaml (followed steps from https://ocaml.org/docs/install.html)
2. Install Opam
3. Run:

   ```
   opam update
   opam pin add flowtype . -n
   opam install --deps-only flowtype
   ```
4. Then, I tried to make it:

   ```
   make
   ```

At the very first seconds, it dies with:

```
ocamlbuild \
        -use-ocamlfind -pkgs compiler-libs.common,unix \
        -I scripts \
        scripts/ppx_gen_flowlibs.native
+ ocamlfind ocamldep -package wtf8 -package dtoa -package unix -package compiler-libs.common -modules scripts/ppx_gen_flowlibs.ml > scripts/ppx_gen_flowlibs.ml.depends
ocamlfind: Package `wtf8' not found
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 1 target (0 cached) in 00:00:01.
Makefile:300: recipe for target '_build/scripts/ppx_gen_flowlibs.native' failed
make: *** [_build/scripts/ppx_gen_flowlibs.native] Error 10
```

It is possible that only I missed something, but I'm not really into OCaml and Opam at the moment.

Comment: Provided an answer to this specific question, but can I ask why you want to modify Flow in the first place?  Perhaps you have a question about Flow that could be answered via `.flowconfig`?

Comment: I've checked the docs and sadly I have to modify the flow a little bit. I'd like to save the call graph/control flow graph it creates, and this is not in their api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pertinent error info appears to be `ocamlfind: Package 'wtf8' not found`.

Have you inited opam?  If not you need to run `opam init --comp 4.03.0` and restart your shell *before* running the other opam commands. (For more detail, see https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Usage.html).

If you have, run `opam list` and see if `wtf8` is in the list of installed packages.  If it is not in the list, try running `opam install wtf8`.  If it *is* in the list, try following the solutions to this same issue here [ocamlfind cannot see installed package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913618/ocamlfind-cannot-see-installed-package).

Comment: Great, thanks for the links. I checked the issue you mentioned and did a totally fresh install and configure, it solved the problem